# When hover on project,display options to edit, delete or copy icons

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Hello i have problem i don't know how to do if I hover on project to show me icons for edit delete or copy.
Here you have my html code.

```
<button button class="vp-button" (click)="opentestdialog()">Add Something
</button>
<button button class="vp-button" (click)="showProject()">Show projects
</button>
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let project of projects$ | async; let i = index;">
        <div class="icon"><span class="fa fa-spinner"></span></div>
        <div class="fa fa-edit clickable edit-icon" (click)="editProject()"></div>
        <div class="fa fa-trash-o clickable delete-icon" (click)="deleteProject(project)"></div>
        <div class="fa fa-files-o clickable copy-item" (click)="copyProject(project)"></div>
        <div class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" (click)="openprojecteditdialog(project)"></div>
        <div *ngIf="!isInputVisible"><td>{{project.name}}</td></div>
        <input [(ngModel)]="project.name" *ngIf="isInputVisible">
        <button button class="vp-button" (click)="onSave(project)" *ngIf="isInputVisible">Save</button>
        <button button class="vp-button" (click)="onCancel()" *ngIf="isInputVisible">Cancel</button>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Show what you have tried and where did you get stuck.

Comment: I don't know how to start, that is the reason i wan't when i hover on that project name should give me these icon classes edit, delete, copy

Comment: You need to create list with your icons inside, hide it and display only when your item gets hovered. Learn more about jquery, it will help you.

Comment: Would you help me i am working with angular in typescript.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at Angular.

Comment: Thank you, maybe someone else can help me in this case.